# Scheduling msbuild task build Nightly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, nunit, scheduler

I am using MSBuild for building our test project from command prompt which inturn uses nunit and gives the results. I want to schedule it nightly so that it automatically runs the msbuild and get the results. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Using batch files - but if you have access to a Team Foundation Server look into its building capabilities, they do what you want and much more.

Comment: right now i am not allowed to use TFS. Is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a [Continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server for this. You can set up your continuous integration server to schedule builds and a number of other tasks. Personally, I use [Team City](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) from Jetbrains, but there are other options available, such as [Cruise Control.net](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) and [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).

What exactly do you want to do with the results? If you just need to run your build script, a simple scheduled task should do it.

Comment: i want to have the results of the test to have it an xml and i need to pull out the xml data.

Comment: Xml test reporting is bundled with Team City as of 4.5, i'm not sure about CC and Hudson.

Answer (score 1):

The way my company solved the problem was to use Powershell. We have a scheduled task that executes a powershell script that completely automates the process using MSBuild and devenv.exe.

We've been able to do away with the expense of many other continuous integration tools with this process. We have even connected it to our svn server so that it can checkout the latest revision, build it, send out an email if there was a build error and send the output of the screen as a result log.

I realize this might not be simple answer you're looking for, but Powershell was really easy for me to learn, exceedingly customizable, and very powerful. I had doubts when my Director said we were moving this way, but it's been a delight.